# Series approximation with integral

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

I have this question and actually the answer too, but didn't understand, can anyone explain further?

> Use series to approximate the values of this integral with an error of magnitude less than $10^{-8}$
>   $$\int_0^{1/2}e^{-x^3}\,dx$$

Comment: Maclaurin's series for $e^{-x^3}$ is an alternating series, so you need to find to which power of $n$ you should take it so that the value of the $n+1$ term evaluated at $x=\frac{1}{2}$ is $<10^{-8}$.

Comment: Please, YOU write the details and tell us exactly what part you do not understand. It is more natural if you show some effort, and it will be a better learning...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
e^x = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{x^n}{n!}
$$
Using the series and applying it to the answer:
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{-x^2} = \left.\sum_{n \ge 0} (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)n!}\right]_0^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{align*}
To be accurate with an error of magnitude less than $10^{-8}$ we go until $n=7$ since 
$$
\frac{(\frac{1}{2})^{15}}{15*7!} < 10^{-8}
$$
Therefore we obtain:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^7 (-1)^n \frac{(\frac{1}{2})^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)n!}
\\
\approx 0.461281006401\ldots
\end{align*}
The actual answer is $0.461281006412\ldots$

EDIT: as a newer user, I understand that you may not have known to put in your attempt. This is beneficial to you and the people answering the problem. Beneficial to you so that we can more accurately help you with the problem you may be having. As well as us for providing a more accurate answer to what you do not understand about the problem. Otherwise it can come off as simply us doing your homework, or something along those lines.